# Lorentz symmetry and associated currents

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, string-theory, tensor-calculus, lorentz-symmetry

The string Lagrangian density is invariant under Lorentz transformations. All terms that appear in this density are of the form $$\eta_{\mu\nu}\frac{\partial X^{\mu}}{\partial\xi^{\alpha}}\frac{\partial X^{\nu}}{\partial\xi^{\beta}}$$ For $X^\mu\rightarrow X^\mu+\epsilon^{\mu\nu}X_{\nu}$

$$\delta\left(\eta_{\mu\nu}\frac{\partial X^{\mu}}{\partial\xi^{\alpha}}\frac{\partial X^{\nu}}{\partial\xi^{\beta}}\right)=\eta_{\mu\nu}\left(\frac{\partial\delta X^{\mu}}{\partial\xi^{\alpha}}\frac{\partial X^{\nu}}{\partial\xi^{\beta}}+\frac{\partial X^{\mu}}{\partial\xi^{\alpha}}\frac{\partial\delta X^{\nu}}{\partial\xi^{\beta}}\right)=$$

$$=\eta_{\mu\nu}\left(\epsilon^{\mu\rho}\frac{\partial X_{\rho}}{\partial\xi^{\alpha}}\frac{\partial X^{\nu}}{\partial\xi^{\beta}}+\epsilon^{\nu\rho}\frac{\partial X^{\mu}}{\partial\xi^{\alpha}}\frac{\partial X_{\rho}}{\partial\xi^{\beta}}\right)=$$

$$
=\epsilon_{\nu\rho}\frac{\partial X^{\rho}}{\partial\xi^{\alpha}}\frac{\partial X^{\nu}}{\partial\xi^{\beta}}+\epsilon_{\mu\rho}\frac{\partial X^{\rho}}{\partial\xi^{\alpha}}\frac{\partial X^{\nu}}{\partial\xi^{\beta}}
$$
where $\eta$ used to lower the indecies on the $\epsilon$ constants. How is the last part could be obtained explicitly?

Comment: Your equations are already as explicit as one could be. What are you looking for?

Comment: Do you agree that $\epsilon^{\mu \rho}$ commutes with $\eta_{\mu\nu}$, and that $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ commutes with $\partial / \partial \xi^{\beta}$?

Comment: I could not lower the indecies of $\epsilon$

Comment: I have$$
\epsilon^{\rho}_{\nu}\frac{\partial X_{\rho}}{\partial\xi^{\alpha}}\frac{\partial X^{\nu}}{\partial\xi^{\beta}}+\epsilon^{\rho}_{\mu}\frac{\partial X^{\mu}}{\partial\xi^{\alpha}}\frac{\partial X_{\rho}}{\partial\xi^{\beta}}
$$

Comment: lower $\rho$ index of $\epsilon$ by writing $\epsilon_\nu{}^\rho = \epsilon_{\nu\tau} \eta^{\tau\rho}$. Then use the $\eta^{\tau\rho}$ to raise the $\rho$ index of $X_\rho$

Comment: Thank you! It is clear now.